# using calloc to create bitmap in C

Tags: c, arrays, bitmap, bit, calloc

If I use an int array as my bitmap, the size I allocate will be (1<<28)/32 right? because int is 32 bits...? And if I want to calloc this space before any functions are called, do I have to do anything special?
**Edit**

I am trying to use calloc to have a bit array where I am able to check and set bits at that array location.

my attempt:

```
    int bitmap[] = calloc(1<<28, 1);
```

and

```
    int bitmap[] = (int*) calloc(1<<28, 1);
```

I am not sure what type the bitmap is or what to cast calloc to...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Why integers? For a bitmap an `unsigned char` array has easier and more intuitive access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't work directly with a "bit array" in C.  You need to use masking / bitshift operators to access individual bits in larger units (at least an 8-bit `char`).

Also, the correct syntax for what you're attempting is:

```
int *bitmap = calloc(1<<28, sizeof(int));
```

which will allocate an array of (1<<28) `int`s.

Access them like this:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i < (1<<28); ++i) {
    bitmap[i] = ...
}
```

Comment: where `SOME_UPPER_BOUND <= (1 << 28)`

Comment: When I use `int *bitmap = calloc(1<<28, sizeof(int));`, I get `error: initializer element is not constant` how can I make it constant?

Comment: You can't. You have to do something like that in a function.

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is better to define the underlying type of the bitmap as `unsigned int` instead of signed int.

As you are using function calloc that returns a pointer then the type of the defined object shall be also a pointer.

```
unsigned int *bitmap = calloc( 1u << 28, sizeof( unsigned int ) );
```

Though I doubt that the first value 1u << 28 is what you indeed need.

Comment: What I need is a large array where I can store if I have seen a value yet or not... So I want everything initialized to 0 and then can later set to 1. So given an unsigned int that is 32 bits, I would initialize like this: `calloc( (1u << 28)/32, sizeof( unsigned int ) );` How can I make it so that I can make this an instance variable (coming from oop), so that everything is set to 0 before I run any methods?!

Comment: @Nick To set all bits to zero you have to use standard function memset.